# Strange gap between adjacent divs in IE8 quirks mode

Tags: internet-explorer-8, quirks-mode, html, gaps-in-visuals

I have a problem with IE8 in quirks mode. I have an outer div element that wraps two inner divs.

```
<div style="margin-left:160px; margin-top:10px; margin-right:0px; height:10px; background:blue;">
    <div style="position:relative; float:left; width:10px; height:10px; background:orange;"></div>
    <div style="position:relative; margin-left:10px; margin-right:0px;height:10px; background:green;"></div>
</div>
```

The inner divs should span the whole of the wrapper div, and it works fine in firefox and chrome. But when I view this in IE8 there is a strange gap between orange div and the green div. Does anyone know how to fix this (or to work around it)? Also, I can't put a doctype declaration anywhere in the document.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute positioning on the content and relative positioning on the container for quirks mode:

```html
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Quirksmode Tests</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="position:relative; margin-left:160px; margin-top:10px; margin-right:0px; height:10px; background-color:blue;">
          <div style="position:absolute; top:0; width:100%; right:0; height:10px; background-color:green;"></div>
          <div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:10px; height:10px; background-color:orange;"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**References**

- [CSS - Quirks mode and strict mode](https://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html)
- [What happens in Quirks Mode in web browsers?](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html)